# Calculating $\mathbb{E}(|B_t|^{-2})$ for 3-dim. Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, expected-value

Ok so I'm given a standard 3-dimensional Brownian motion $B(t) = (B_{1}(t),B_{2}(t),B_{3}(t))$, function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ and the process $A(t) = f(B(t))$ and $t \in [1;\infty)$

I need to calculate $E[A^2(t)]$.

---

What I did:

I used Ito's formula for the function $f(t,x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$  and ended up with

$d(f(t,x,y,z)) = -x(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}dx - y(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}dy - z(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}dz$

At this point I'm lost.

$f(0)$ is infinity, so i'm not sure what is going on. Can I even go further and claim, that $A(t)$ = sum of 3 integrals?

Now, if I just forget abut this issue above and go directly for the square, I get:

$E[A^2(t)] = \int_{1}^{t}E[\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}]ds$ using the ito isometry and the fubini-tonelli theorem.

And I don't know what to do. Apparently the answer is $\frac{1}{t}$ but for some reason I can't comprehend what am I supposed to do there. Can I go into triple integral and change to spherical coordinates? Also, this constraint on $t$, am I right to assume, that the integration limits will therefore be from 1 and not from 0?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see that Itô's formula is of much use for this problem (in particular, since there is the sinularity at zero which means that you would need to work with local times). It's much easier to use the fact that we know the transition density of $(B_t)$.

---

By the very definition of $A(t)$, we need to compute

$$\mathbb{E}(A^2(t)) = \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{|B_t|^2} \right).$$

Plugging in the transition density of $B_t$ we find that

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{|B_t|^2} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2} \exp \left( - \frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{2t} \right) \, d(x,y,z).$$

Introducing polar coordinates we get

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{|B_t|^2} \right) &= \frac{4\pi}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^3} \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{r^2} \exp \left(- \frac{r^2}{2t} \right) \, (r^2 \, dr) \\ &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t^3}} \int_{(0,\infty)} \exp \left(- \frac{r^2}{2t} \right) \, dr. \end{align*}$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{|B_t|^2} \right) &=\frac{1}{t} \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \exp \left(- \frac{r^2}{2t} \right) \, dr}_{=1} = \frac{1}{t}. \end{align*}$$

Comment: Amazing, I just want to clarify a few things:

1. The so called transition density - why do you call it like that? I know the different, completely unrelated to this scenario definition of transition density. To me it looked like you just used 3 normal PDFs for each variable, multiplied them (so you ended up with a summ in the power of exponent) and then integrated 3 times over R.

2. I think you have a typo in the 3rd line from the bottom: the "2" has to be in the denominator.

3. Why when using ito formula I did not get the same value for the $A^2(t)?$

4. What about condition on t?

Comment: @Makina 1. The name "transition density" is coming from Markov theory.. if you prefer, you can call it probability density function. 2. No, it's not a typo. If you think so because the $2$ is in the denominator in the very last line, then be aware that the domain of integration changed from $\int_{(0,\infty)}$ to $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$ from line 3 to line 1 (from the bottom); we used symmetry here. 3. As already mentioned you cannot apply Itô's formula because $f$ is not a twice differentiable bounded function. 4. Obviously we need $t>0$; apart from that there is no condition.

Comment: Ok, I see now, yep, I missed this coordinate change detail. Alright, thank you very much. The reason I was insisting on ito was because another part of this exercise required me to prove that A(t) is a local martingale but not the true martingale. Local martingale, I believe, is possible to prove via Ito's expansion, where the only non-zero term in the expansion is the diffusion term. True martingale is proven, if I'm not wrong, if the expected value of the square of the diffusion is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach.

1) $$E[e^{-s|B_t|^2}] = E[e^{-ts N(0,1)^2}]^3.$$

2) \begin{align*} E[e^{-u N(0,1)^2}] & = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int e^{-x^2 ( u + 1/2) }dx\\
 & = (2u+1)^{-1/2}.
\end{align*}

3) $$x^{-1} = \int_0^\infty e^{-s x} ds.$$

Putting it all together:

\begin{align*}  E [|B_t|^{-2} ] & = E [\int_0^\infty [e^{-s|B_t|^2} ]ds \\
 & = \int_0^\infty E [ e^{-s|B_t|^2}] ds \\
 & = \int_0^\infty (2st+1)^{-3/2} ds \\
 & = -\frac{2}{(2t)}(2st+1)^{-1/2} \left.\right|_{s=0}^{s=\infty}\\
 & = \frac{1}{t}
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Although your solution looks much more succinct compared to mr. saz, I can't help but be confused about some of the notations used and the results. I just want to confirm.

1. There you just used the MGF of jointly normal 3 random variables

2. MGF of squared normal random variable

3. Smart substitution.